# Representation-finiteness vs. $\tau$-tilting-finiteness

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, associative-algebras

***Setting***: Throughout, $\Lambda$ is a finite dimensional associative algebra, $\operatorname{mod} \Lambda$ is the category of all finitely generated left $\Lambda$-modules, and all subcategories are assumed to be full.

***Background***: As motivated from the viewpoint of mutation, $\tau$-tilting theory is a completion of tilting theory, as every almost support $\tau$-tilting module has exactly two ways to complete to a support $\tau$-tilting module.
That said, $\tau$-tilting theory also somehow paves the way for a generalization of representation finite algebras. Because, $\tau$-tilting finiteness of $\Lambda$ is equivalent to the fact that every torsion class $\mathcal{T}$ in $\operatorname{mod} \Lambda$ is functorially finite -- the property which holds for every subcategory if and only if $\Lambda$ is finite representation type.

***Question***: Has it been studied for which families of algebras (e.g. Nakayama, gentle, etc.) these two notions coincide? In other words, is it known for which algebras $\tau$-tilting finiteness implies representation finiteness?

I would appreciate the answers accompanied by reference.

Comment: This will probably sound silly, since I think your question has only one reasonable interpretation: but do I understand correctly that you are asking for some 'named' families (e.g. Nakayama, gentle, etc.) of algebras which are only $\tau$-tilting finite when they are representation finite?

Comment: @MatthewPressland That's right Matthew, I was just wondering if for any known class of algebras, such as the ones you mentioned, it has been shown that $\tau$-tilting finiteness and representation finiteness are the same. 
Obviously, every representation finite algebra is $\tau$-tilting finite, so the missing direction is the other one.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I think it might help to change the wording under 'Question' slightly to reflect this---at the moment it reads to me as if you are asking for 'the' class for which the two notions coincide, i.e. representation-finite algebras! Apologies if this seems fussy, but the slight conflict between what is actually written and what I thought the question must be caused me a little confusion at first.

Comment: @MatthewPressland Thanks for your comments. It surely sounds better with the suggested wording. I apply the change.

Comment: For gentle algebras see https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.06313 by Pierre-Guy Plamondon.

Comment: And asking this question for Nakayama algebras is not very interesting, since they are always representation finite...

Comment: @Jabby Thanks for your comments and the reference. I have been aware of the recent work of Plamondon on gentle algebras, but I appreciate mentioning that.
As you pointed out, in terms of $\tau$-tilting finiteness, there is not much to say about any class of representation-finite algebras. So, since last winter I conducted an investigation on Special Biserial Algebras to address some generalization of the questions I posed last year in this post. 
My work is at the closing stage and in preparation and I will probably add a link to this post once it becomes available on arXiv.